# Facebook Webhooks To Find Who Likes Your Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a webhook setup to watch the 'feed' field on a FB page I am an admin of.  I am trying to keep track of WHO likes our PAGE, not posts on the page.

So far it seems to be very erratic about the hooks it sends for Page Likes.  I have only seen one of them fire, and it does not seem to include the user info, only that somebody liked the page. Example response below.

```
 +"entry": array:1 [▼
      0 => {#1535 ▼
        +"changes": array:1 [▼
          0 => {#1533 ▼
            +"field": "feed"
            +"value": {#1534 ▼
              +"item": "like"
              +"verb": "add"
            }
          }
        ]
        +"id": "15093830XXXXXXXX"
        +"time": 1561391263
      }
    ]
    +"object": "page"
  }
```

Is there anyway to automatically find who likes your page? Even another endpoint I can call once this trigger fires, to get the list of people and do a diff?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: what´s the use case for this?

Comment: @WizKid after reading up all night, that is the conclusion I am coming to as well.  I knew Facebook had locked their API down since the CambridgeAnalytica scandal, but seems they have made it borderline useless.  As a page owner, there is no way to automatically get a list of people who like my own page. That seems like a major fail.

Comment: @luschn The use case was, to gather a list of people who like my page in realtime as it happens. We have a live festival where we purchased a vendor booth.  If you like our page during the event, you can enter a raffle.

Comment: You should really read https://developers.facebook.com/policy . It is not allowed to incentives anyone to like your page

Comment: I have read it several times. Like many things in the Facebook ecosystem, certain things are unclear, or ambiguous, and FB provides bare minimum support resources to answer developer questions.  What would "enter a promotion on your app’s Page" mean to you?

Comment: Not that it truly matters what the use case is. A page owner cannot get the users who like their page programmatically.  That in and of itself is ridiculous to me.

Comment: it´s just a like with a single button click, the user did not agree to anything else. anyway, users need to like (or share) something because they really want to, not because they get something for it. that is pretty much the opposite of ridiculous imho :)

Comment: either way, that´s just opinions. the only important thing to know is that it is not allowed. "enter a promotion on your app`s page" means that you can take part in a promotion by commenting on a page post, for example.